# pandas dataframe merge, ValueError, dtype mismatch

Tags: python, pandas

```
   In [152] df1.dtypes

  Out [152] id                        int64
            user_id                   int64
            area_ids                 object
            areas                    object
            birth_date               object
            birth_date_at    datetime64[ns]
            age_month                 int64
            age_year                float64
            age_bin                category
            dtype: object

   In [153] df2.dtypes

  Out [153] review_meta_id    int64
            search_log_id     int64
            dtype: object

   In [154] pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on="search_log_id", right_on="id")
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
            ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
            Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.lib.is_bool_array'
            ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

  Out [154]
```

Why is the error?

It seems the `age_bin` category column is causing the problem. If I omit the data, merge works fine

Data looks like the following

```
   In [155] df1

  Out [155]

                id       user_id  area_ids  areas             birth_date  birth_date_at  age_month  age_year  age_bin
              0 33722    3969     [1988]    [파주/일산]       2012-12-10  2012-12-10     95         7.916667  8
              1 33724    3969     [1988]    [파주/일산]       2012-12-10  2012-12-10     95         7.916667  8
              2 33725    3969     [1988]    [파주/일산]       2012-12-10  2012-12-10     95         7.916667  8
              3 33726    3969     [1995]    [경기도전체]      2012-12-10  2012-12-10     95         7.916667  8
              4 2833779  3969     [2878]    [제주특별자치도]  2012-12-10  2012-12-10     95         7.916667  8


   In [156] df2

  Out [156]

                review_meta_id  search_log_id
              0 1307            1346076
              1 3282            1346076
              2 4039            1346076
              3 940             1346076
              4 4148            1346076
```

Comment: It looks for me like bug, what pandas version use?

Comment: 0.21.0 @jezrael

Comment: It is old, I think upgrade solve this problem.

Comment: @jezrael yeah, it goes away after upgrade..

Comment: it's answered. so make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in old pandas version, here pandas 0.21.0, upgrading to last one solve problem.